# Lazyloading of EntityCollection

Tags: entity-framework

I’m using entity framework 5.
I’m trying to lazy load an entity collection, I stripped the model to the bare bones to have a simple runable sample.

This is my model:

```
public class A
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EntityCollection<B> Bs
    {
        get { return bs; }
        set { bs = value; }
    }
    private EntityCollection<B> bs;

    public A()
    {
        bs = new EntityCollection<B>();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
}

public class DbModel : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                    .HasKey( t => t.Id )
                    .HasMany(a => a.Bs)
                    .WithRequired(b => b.A);
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                    .Property(t => t.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                    .HasKey(b => b.Id)
                    .HasRequired(b => b.A);
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                    .Property( t => t.Id )
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity );
    }
```

This is the test demonstrating my problem:

```
   [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        model = new DbModel();
        model.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        if (model.Database.Exists()) model.Database.Delete();

        model.Database.Create();
        A a = model.As.Create();
        model.As.Add(a);
        B b = model.Bs.Create();
        a.Bs.Add(b);

        model.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        model.SaveChanges();
    }

   [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // arrange
        DbModel tModel = new DbModel();
        A a = tModel.As.First();

        // act
        a.Bs.Load();
    }
```

This is the result:

Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Requested operation is not allowed
>   when the owner of this RelatedEnd is null. RelatedEnd objects that
>   were created with the default constructor should only be used as a
>   container during serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was using classes from different paradigms of the ADO family.
As pointed out by Gert Arnold EF doesn’t work with EntityCollection it uses a plain list for association collections.

```
public class A
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<B> Bs
    {
        get { return bs; }
        set { bs = value; }
    }
    private List<B> bs = new List<B>();
}
```

As I did not want the proxies, the objects have no “knowledge” of the model. So the model itself has to be used to load associations for an entity.
For this sample I added the following method to the model:

```
public class DbModel : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

//…

    public A LoadAWithAssociations(A targetA)
    {
        return As.Include("Bs").First(a => a.Id.Equals(targetA.Id));
    }
}
```

I adapted the test to use the new method

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // arrange
        DbModel tModel = new DbModel();
        A a = tModel.As.First();

        // act
        A result =  tModel.LoadAWithAssociations(a);

        // assert 
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Bs.Count > 0);
    }
```

It gives a green now

Answer (score 1):

`EntitySet` is part of the linq-to-sql API. That does not explain this particular exception, but a less than smooth cooperation with DbContext is no surprise. When you use DbContext API it is common to define a 1:n navigation property as an interface like `ICollection`:

```
public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
```

(`virtual` to enable proxy creation for lazy loading)

As an aside: you can use `model.Database.Delete()` without checking whether the database exists. And `DetectChanges()` right before `SaveChanges()` is redundant.

Comment: thanks for the help. Do have to reload the object with the include syntax to load a collection (I don't like the proxy generation and like to stay with POCO's). Gave you my upvote for the poiters!

Comment: Of course `virtual` is just optional, but `EntitySet` is certainly not in place here.

Comment: It looks like I mixed stuff from two different frameworks. I gues there is no (good) way to load properties from the Entities themselfs without using porxies. Used them with NHibernate and dit not like it. Things in the model should be virtual for model related reasons, not for some DAL imposed proxy scheme.

Comment: It's a mild compromise. I worked with NHibernate and some other less well known OR mappers, and now work with EF. They all have their footprints in the domain. I decided to join them where I can't beat them. Another footprint is the exposure of primitive FK values besides the pure object oriented references (in EF terms: _foreign key associations_ as opposed to _independent associations_). Makes life so much easier that it really does not make sense to stay an OO purist at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted, this code. Do you really want a class (B) that contains a reference to class A that in turn has a collection of B? Maybe it's just the obfuscated names, but I can't imagine a scenario for an object model like this.

In any case, my instinct would be to look for a circular reference or another condition that is preventing an object property to be instantiated on one of your classes.

Also, you are using Eager loading in the test method using a.Bs.Load(). Lazy Loading is disabled when you set ProxyCreationEnabled = false.

Comment: yes i do not normally have classes called a and b. It is the bare bones code needed to demo my problem